# about the flip of row and columns using pheatmap package

Tags: r

Does pheatmap package has the function of flipping row and column?

https://davetang.org/muse/2018/05/15/making-a-heatmap-in-r-with-the-pheatmap-package/

Answer (score 1):

If you transpose the input matrix (with `t()`) you can 'flip' rows and columns. Using your example:

```
# install package
install.packages("pheatmap")
# load package
library(pheatmap)
# install DESeq if necessary
if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
  install.packages("BiocManager")
BiocManager::install("DESeq")
# load package
library("DESeq")

# load data and subset
example_file <- system.file ("extra/TagSeqExample.tab", package="DESeq")
data <- read.delim(example_file, header=T, row.names="gene")
data_subset <- as.matrix(data[rowSums(data)>50000,])

# create heatmap using pheatmap
pheatmap(data_subset)
pheatmap(t(data_subset))
```

[image: Heatmap_1]
[image: Heatmap_2]